Как получить все переменные из выражения в библиотеке sympy?
Допустим, мы получаем какую-то строку и далее переводим ее в выражение sympy
from sympy import *

x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')
line = "(x ** 2 * y ** 2) / (2 * z)"
formula = parse_expr(line)

Как из получившейся формулы получить переменные, содержащиеся в ней? (В данном случае - x, y, z)?
И можно ли это сделать?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58258497/22294930 - formula.free_symbols
